# Merge a large list of logical vectors

Tags: r, list, merge, bigdata

I have a large list of `TRUE/FALSE` logical vectors (144 list elements, each ~ 23 million elements long). I want to merge them using `any` to produce one logical vector. If any of the first elements of each list element are `TRUE` then `TRUE` is returned and so on for the length of the vectors. Here's an example:

```
#  Some data
set.seed(1)
ll <- replicate(3,sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),5,TRUE),simplify=F)

#[[1]]
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

#[[2]]
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

#[[3]]
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

#  What I want (and one way of doing it)...
apply( do.call(cbind,ll) , 1 , any )
#  [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

---

#### Wait, you already posted a solution in that code, why ask the question?

I have 144 vectors, each of 23,721,703 length in my real data. Attempting the above throws errors such as:

```
# *** caught segfault ***
#address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

OR

#Error in aperm.default(X, c(s.call, s.ans)) : 
#  long vectors not supported yet: memory.c:1648
```

I'm running R 3.0.2 on Ubuntu 64bit with 112Gb RAM.

Comment: Not sure if this helps or not, `Reduce('|', ll)`

Comment: No need to cbind all 144 vectors at once. Break it up into multiple passes. Compare the first 10. then the next. Or whatever load the cpu can handle. `any(cbind(first10vectors))` will output one logical vector that can be compared to `any(cbind(newvector, next10vectors))`.

Comment: @akrun thank you both. These are both excellent suggestions. I am trying the `Reduce` method first, I'll let you know if it works - takes a while to read all the data in (across a slowish network connection in a cloud VM).

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon Based on 1e5 size list elements, `Reduce` is faster on `system.time` .  But, I didn't use bigger datasets.

Comment: @akrun speed isn't necessarily my chief concern - it's more I actually want the operation to complete (albeit in a reasonable time frame). I'm using `data.table` so my real call will be `dt[ , lapply( .SD , function(x) x == "?" ) , .SDcols = 4:ncol(dt) ][ , Reduce('|',.SD) ]` which works nicely in a test case. Let's see....

Comment: @akrun `Reduce` turns out to be a perfect solution for this. I have a few operations that I needed to run and I could translate them all to a `Reduce` function and successively combine them. Would you like to write an answer so I can give you credit, or would you like me to, describing my actual use-case? Cheers.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon Thanks, I  guess combining `Reduce` within the `data.table` made the difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Reduce`

```
  Reduce('|', ll)
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(1)
ll <- replicate(144, sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1e5,
       replace=TRUE), simplify=FALSE)
system.time(apply(do.call(cbind, ll), 1, any))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.575   0.022   0.598 

system.time(Reduce(`|`, ll))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.287   0.008   0.295
```

Comment: `rowSums(do.call(cbind, ll))>0` is much better than the `apply( )` code, but still slower than `Reduce( )`...